# Cant get pact tests running with Karma and Angular

Tags: angular, karma-runner, pact

I can not get pact tests to run at all with Karma with my Angular app setup. Here is the relevant part from package.json.

```
"@angular/core": "~13.3.6",
"@pact-foundation/karma-pact": "^3.1.0",
"@pact-foundation/pact": "^9.17.3",
"@pact-foundation/pact-node": "^10.17.4"
"jasmine-core": "~3.8",
"karma": "^6.3.19",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^5.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0"
```

karma.config.json

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular', 'pact'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
            require('@pact-foundation/karma-pact')
        ],
        files: [
            'polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-web/pact-web.js'
        ],
        client: {
            jasmine: {
                // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
                // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
                // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
                // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
            },
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        jasmineHtmlReporter: {
            suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/spa'),
            subdir: '.',
            reporters: [
                {type: 'html'},
                {type: 'text-summary'}
            ]
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true,
        pact: [
            {
                cors: true,
                spec: 3,
                port: 1234,
                consumer: 'consumer',
                provider: 'provider',
                logLevel: 'DEBUG',
                dir: 'pacts'
            }
        ],
    });
};
```

I used `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` and this is extra webpackconfig to add polyfills:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

    module.exports = {
        plugins: [
            new NodePolyfillPlugin()
        ],
        externals: {
            "fs": require('fs'),
            "child_process": require('child_process'),
            "net": require('net')
        }
    };
```

I' am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readFile')
```

If I configure it like this:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "fs": false,
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ],
    externals: {
        "child_process": require('child_process'),
        "net": require('net')
    }
};
```

I get this error:

```
 An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAbsolute' of '__webpack_require__(...).win32' as it is null.
  TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAbsolute' of '__webpack_require__(...).win32' as it is null.
      at Object.79857 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/tar/lib/strip--path.js:3:9)
```

Setting target to node in webpack config does not help, just then getting the error that `module` is not defined.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We'd probably need a repository to reproduce this problem. That being said, it looks like Webpack is trying to pack the `@pact-foundation/pact` package, which won't work (I can see mention of tar and win32, both of which are only used on the server side) - this might be a clue.

I'd also just make the comment that the karma support (and indeed, pact web) is not likely to be supported going forward and I would suggest you test this outside of Karma (e.g. in Jest, Mocha etc.) using the standard `@pact-foundation/pact` package.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I would have to make a separate repo for this, it could take time, I can not make this one public. I spent the whole day yesterday trying to make it work, but no progress. In the end, I added jest package just to run pact tests and it works fine. I left Karma as it was for angular unit tests.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I'd do. Separate the tests out.